# typo3 check all backend user( not only admin)

Tags: php, typo3-4.5

in my backend I have admin and managers. Managers have short functional. But I want show some content ALL backend users, not only admins. I use `$this->tsfe->beUserLogin` construction, and this content visible only for admins.

**UPD**  I have FE module, it placed into several page. In my extension I have .php and .tpl files. I transmit `$variable=$GLOBALS['TSFE']->beUserLogin` from .php to .tpl file, and in .tpl I have construction `if(variable) <div>...</div>`. In the page I don't have div, if I don't have admin account. 
`if($GLOBALS['TSFE']->beUserLogin) die('Logged BE user');` if I am admin, it's work, but for another users script continue work.The managers have access only to folder with content element, but don't have to page, where this content placed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more explicit, what your actual problem is. Btw. you are using a TYPO3 version that is out of support since a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common backend user (not admin) need to have the access to the page at least possibility to see it on the Page tree (in **WEB>Access** module at least first option (*ShowPage)* must be marked for the group of the user)

Otherwise the `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->beUserLogin` var considers there's no logged BE user (or there's no BE user allowed to see this page as an admin).